# How to use torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel in this case?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, distributed-computing, distributed-system

In my case, the training data is too large to save in one single computer or one computing node in a cluster (due to the limited disk space in each node), so it is split into several parts and each part is saved in one computing node. Suppose there are 3 computing nodes: `A`, `B`, and `C`. The folder for saving the part 1 in `A` is the `/data/training_data/part1/`, the folder for saving the part 2 in `B` is the `/data/training_data/part2/`, and the folder for saving the part 3 in `C` is the `/data/training_data/part3/`.

Then, how do I train a convolutional neural network using the `torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel` in this circumstance?
Could you please give some advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Federated Learning might be a solution.